# Getting an XamlObjectWriterException only at design time with MultiBindingConverter (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I've narrowed the cause as a MultiBindingConverter I'm using to calculate the an angle used in a transform.

I've stripped it down to as minimal as I can get. Here's the code for my listbox:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Int32}" x:Key="Cards">
        <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
    </x:Array>
    <local:FanPositionCalculator x:Key="FanPositionCalculator"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource Cards}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="5,25,55,15">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform>
                        <RotateTransform.Angle>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FanPositionCalculator}">
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource Cards}"/>
                                <Binding Path=""/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RotateTransform.Angle>
                    </RotateTransform>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The multibinding fans out the contents based on a calculation of it's index. To do this I used a multi-binding converter:

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int count = (values[0] as IList).Count;
        int itemIndex = (values[0] as IList).IndexOf(values[1]);

        double indexFromCenter = itemIndex - count / 2;

        //multiply by the degrees we want for each card
        return indexFromCenter * 3;
    }
```

The first value passed is the list of objects. The second is the object in question. It calculates the angle to rotate it.

It works fine when I run it:

[image]

However, it kills the whole designer at design time:

[image]

The error is an XamlObjectWriterException:

```
Collection property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding'.'Source' is null.

at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteGetObject()
at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
```

Which I'm at a loss how to fix. There's no errors in my converter, but it's presence causes this error to occur in the Window the list is in (not the list itself!). Any ideas on how to fix it? I was wondering if I could just skip using the converter during design-time. I'm happy with un-rotated cards being displayed... I'm not happy with the whole designer dying though, so I'd like to solve it. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to step through the XamlLoader code to see it but, based on what I observed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41604891/2670182), I think there is a bug in it.
As it parses the xaml, the XamlLoader recurses on the elements, maintaining a context stack as it goes. When it recurses into the Resources element, it establishes the value for the Cards array by reading the xaml and setting a value in that context, either immediately or as a deferred value.  It then pops the stack and continues parsing. When it recurses on the ListView, it creates a new context but that context does not seem to receive the value for the static resource.  Meanwhile, the XamlLoader assumes that it has and writes the unset (null) value to the receiving property (in your case, the Binding Source) and this causes the error.

In other words, WPF seems (to me anyway) to be confused about values set in one parsing context and consumed in another.  The workaround is to minimise the different contexts.  In your case, this means setting the Resources on the ListView instead of the Window.  The ItemsSource needs to be set using Object Element Syntax, which you can then reference using a RelativeSource.  I like to instantiate the RelativeSource in the element resources as well because I think it's cleaner.

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="5,25,55,15">
    <ListView.Resources >
        <RelativeSource x:Key="List" Mode="FindAncestor" 
                    AncestorType="{x:Type ListView}" />
        <local:FanPositionCalculator x:Key="FanPositionCalculator"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type system:Int32}" x:Name="Cards">
            <system:Int32>2</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>4</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>3</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>5</system:Int32>
            <system:Int32>1</system:Int32>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform>
                        <RotateTransform.Angle>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FanPositionCalculator}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{StaticResource List}" Path="ItemsSource"/>
                                <Binding Path=""/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RotateTransform.Angle>
                    </RotateTransform>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'm using VS 2017 RC and this fixes the design view for me and same result for VS 2013 so, should work for you also.
[image]

Comment: Well done! Wasn't expecting this to be solved. I'd given up. One thing, it's probably simpler just to bind directly to the ItemsSource of the ListView in the multibinind rather than to create a ListView resource to hold it's own ItemsSource: <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}" Path="ItemsSource"/>. That avoids the whole Resource thing altogether.

Comment: Hey @Joe: no worries and yes, true dat. I wasn't really thinking about the basic stuff I guess, my brain was fried trying to trace the XamlObjectWriter.

Comment: Quite genius to instantiate the `RelativeSource` markup extension as a resource using **XAML tag syntax**. Kudos for that. However that part of your invention (at least) doesn't seem to necessitate that "The `ItemsSource` [be] set using Object Element Syntax," as you say. Once you've escaped the template and bound to the `ListView` using that trick (which is the hard part), it shouldn't matter what XAML syntax was used to establish that instance's `ItemsSource`, right? Or were you addressing a different part of the OP's question with that remark? Again, outstanding work.