# Getting an XamlObjectWriterException only at design time with ValueConverter inside DataTemplate (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, wpf, app.xaml

I have an application which runs perfectly at run-time but fails at design time with **Collection property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding'.'ConverterParameter' is null exception.**

I think I have narrowed it down to the fact that I am referencing an x:array static resource (declared in resource dictionary, merged in App.xaml) in a value converter inside a DataTemplate.

If I use the same code outside a DataTemplate, I do not get this problem.
I suspect that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762876/getting-an-xamlobjectwriterexception-only-at-design-time-with-multibindingconver) has the same root cause.

I have re-created the problem:

In Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:trial_app_for_x_array_issue.Resources">

<x:Array x:Key="VisibilityArrayFalseCollapsed" Type="Visibility">
    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
</x:Array>
```

In the DataConverter:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace trial_app_for_x_array_issue.Converters
{
    public class BoolToVisibilityMultiParamConverter : IValueConverter

    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Check for design mode.
            if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue))
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }

            if (value is bool && targetType == typeof(Visibility))
            {
                Array arr = parameter as Array;
                if (null != arr && arr.Length == 2)
                {
                    bool ValueEqTrue = (bool)value;
                    if (ValueEqTrue)
                    {
                        return arr.GetValue(0);
                    }
                    return arr.GetValue(1);
                }
            }
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and in MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="trial_app_for_x_array_issue.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:trial_app_for_x_array_issue.Converters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:BoolToVisibilityMultiParamConverter x:Key="MultiParamBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Expander>
        <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Name="CurrentActivityPercentageTextBlock"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Hello World"
                           Visibility="{Binding CurrentActivities.IsIndeterminate,
                                                Converter={StaticResource MultiParamBoolToVisibilityConverter},
                                                ConverterParameter={StaticResource VisibilityArrayFalseCollapsed}}" />

            </DataTemplate>
        </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

If I take the TextBox out of the DataTemplate, there are no errors.

Incidentally, if I use another type instead of x:array, there is no exception so it seems (to me at least) to be something to do with the use of x:array resource inside a DataTemplate.

I have now run out of ideas ...

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the setter for the `Parameter` property of the `Converter` class (you will need dotpeek as a symbol server and set a function breakpoint) I suspect you will find that it's set twice: first time with correct value, second time with null. I think there is a bug in the `XamlObjectWriter` class.

Comment: Thank you Cool Blue, I will download Dot peek now and give it a try. (This could be "interesting": I have never done this kind of break-pointing before)

Comment: hmm, Hi CoolBlue , any chance of giving me a clue how you do this ?  I have set up symbol server but after that, I am kinda stuck.

Comment: I gave you a bum steer in the above comments, I attempted to answer the other question you mentioned so, maybe that will help you.  Meanwhile, in your case, the binding will fail as written because the data context of the HeaderTemplate is the Header property of the Expander, which is null, so the converter will not fire.

Comment: By the way, [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=uielement) is some information on how to step through the wpf source code. Now that you have the symbol server set up you should be able to do this. Also, a lot of the WPF source code in in this site which is usefull sometimes if you get stuck.

Comment: I think "thank you" comments get taken down but it feels really rude NOT to say thank you for all you help and I know of no other way of doing it on this site (new to me) .  Incidentally, your solution worked for me so brilliant :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this looks like a bug in the XamlLoader.  It seems to struggle with linking its various parsing contexts.
Not very Dry but, you can fix it by moving the array to the DataTemplate Resources. I'm not sure what you were doing with the binding for Visibility (as mentioned in my comment) so I set the Expander.Header property to an appropriate value in order to establish the correct data context for the DataTemplate...

```
<Window x:Class="SO_41650679_2670182.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:SO_41650679_2670182.Converters"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <RelativeSource x:Key="View" Mode="FindAncestor"
                        AncestorType="{x:Type Window}" />
        <converters:BoolToVisibilityMultiParamConverter x:Key="MultiParamBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="{Binding RelativeSource={StaticResource View}, Path=CurrentActivities.IsIndeterminate}">
            Hello World
            <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <x:Array x:Key="VisibilityArrayFalseCollapsed" Type="Visibility">
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </x:Array>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Name="CurrentActivityPercentageTextBlock"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="Header"
                               Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MultiParamBoolToVisibilityConverter},
                                                ConverterParameter={StaticResource VisibilityArrayFalseCollapsed}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        </Expander>
        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Height="30"
                      IsChecked="{Binding CurrentActivities.IsIndeterminate, 
                                  RelativeSource={StaticResource View}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Although this gets rid of the design time error, it causes a warning about 
`No default constructor found for type 'System.Windows.Visibility[]'` (I have no idea what it's problem is...) and your design time converter code path doesn't seem to work either.